# Black screen after login. Partition with Windows 7 + Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: system-installation, 17.04

Similar questions have been asked, but none pertain to my situation. I partitioned the my hard drive with a USB giving Ubuntu 100.4GB. I go to login and the desktop flickers then disappears. The cursor is still visible, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> the cursor disappears. This makes the screen appear then flicker out.

```
sudo apt purge lightdm
sudo apt update
sudo apt install lightdm
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

<kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> menu isn’t visible, but still works (This is the first time I have used Ubuntu). Running with unity 8 works. but is really slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved very easily. I was not using nvideas proprietary, tested drivers. To fix the issue, if you can plug in another graphics card, for me I just used my CPU’s inbuilt graphics and changed these settings under devices and drivers.